# cygwin, perl, dos version of abspath()?

Tags: perl, path, cygwin

When running cygwin perl, is there a way to get the DOS absolute path from a cygwin path?
Ideally it would also resolve cygwin symlinks.

E.g.:

```
'/cygdrive/c/foo' -> 'C://foo'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a shell:

```
cygpath -wa /cygdrive/c/foo
```

From perl:

```
system("cygpath", "-wa", "/cygdrive/c/foo")
```

I haven't tested this with symlinks.

Comment: To do the opposite (Windows path to Unix path), use -u instead of -w. Since -u is the default, you may also omit it: cygpath -a c:/foo